# How to print a dependency graph of pytest fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest, directed-acyclic-graphs

`pytest` lets you redefine fixtures defined at upper levels, and this redefinition propagates up the fixture tree. Example:

```py
# tests/conftest.py
@pytest.fixture()
def foo(): ...
    
@pytest.fixture()
def bar(): ...
    
@pytest.fixture()
def baz(foo, bar): ...
    
@pytest.fixture()
def fizz(foo, baz, capsys): ...

# tests/deep/down/test_something.py

@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    return "something completely different"

def test_something(fizz, other, fixtures):
    # For this test, `foo` is replaced with our fixture everywhere
    # in fizz's tree (meaning: both `fizz` and `buzz` receiver our
    # version of `foo`)
    
@pytest.mark.parameterize("foo", ["a", "b", "c"])
def test_something_else(fizz, even, more, fixtures):
    # Same here
```

This is a powerful technique, but it's sometimes hard to follow the fixture chain.
I commonly need to answer questions such as: "*what are the steps from `foo` to `fizz`?*", "*which of the 3 fixtures this test depends on are affected by `foo`?*".

Is there a way I can print the dependency graph so that it's easier to make sense of it? Something like this:

```
 foo  bar
 ^ ^   ^
 |  \ /
 |  baz    buzz
 |  ^      ^
 | /------/
fizz
```

I have found that I can print the list of all fixtures with `pytest --fixtures tests_folder/`, but it doesn't show the fixtures' dependencies. Is there a way to build this dependency graph?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `--setup-plan`?

```text
pytest --setup-plan
```

The help reads

```text
$ pytest --help
...
test session debugging and configuration:
...
  --setup-only          only setup fixtures, do not execute tests.
  --setup-show          show setup of fixtures while executing tests.
  --setup-plan          show what fixtures and tests would be executed but don't execute anything.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the [pytest-fixture-tools](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-fixture-tools) package, which builds a beautiful graph like this for each individual test:
[image: Screenshot of fixture graph in VSCode]

This is not quite what I want (it's not a static graph of fixture dependencies), but it's definitely helpful for my purposes.